# Difference between calabash and appium

Tags: appium, calabash

Currently I'm working with mobile testing. I want to automate our mobile app. So I found some tools are appium and calabash. I want to know the difference between both and which tools is most people using and which tools is more easy to use ? I'm working a small company here I'm the only tester. So somebody please clear me and how to select a tool ?

Comment: We won't be able to tell you which tool most people are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few differences between Appium and Calabash

1. Appium support Many Languages Java, C#, Ruby, Python, JavaScript, But Calabash supports only is Ruby.
2. Calabash has two projects running in parallel: Calabash-Android and Calabash-iOS
   In Appium: both Android and iOS are clubbed into one.
3. Appium has a recording option that would be useful for beginners in software testing company
4. Calabash cannot automate the browser. Appium can do.

Comment: Edited item #4 since Calabash can automate webviews. Did that myself. Here are a couple of references: Android: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/wiki/06-webview-support; iOS: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/06-WebView-Support

Answer (score 1):

I think appium is widly using by the testers.And also you can get more help from the commiunity if you are moving with appium.
And also so many video tutorials available for appium too.